# Rearrange Headings Alphabetically

Tags: control-panel

Is there a way (or plugin) to organise headings alphabetically? You can drag and drop to rearrange but if its a contact list for example, being alphabetised is really useful.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My headings were created alphabetically but Z-A not A-Z, I solved by modifying the dom elements and then clicking save.

```
var source = document.querySelector('.cs-sidebar .sources');
var divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cs-sidebar .sources .customize-sources-item')];
divs = divs.slice(0).reverse();
source.innerHTML = '';
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  source.appendChild(divs[i]);
}
```